# HEMT/PHEMT transistor circuit design- need manual/book

Tags: transistors, amplifier, microwave

I have to design a microwave amplifier in the frequency range of 0-15GHz. To this end, I need to be able to design circuits with HEMT/PHEMT transistors. Is there a comprehensible manual that teaches precisely how to deal with and manipulate such transistors? I prefer online manual, but books are also welcome. I'm not a professional electrical engineer, so, I need practical explanations of how to build circuits with such transistors.

Comment: Gigahenries (GH) is not a unit of frequency.

Comment: I doubt if you'll find a single book. Most people who do that kind of design start by getting a PhD. Also, the kind of frequency rang you're asking for probably means a cascode amplifier, and you'll have a hard time building that from individual transistors if you don't have access to your own fab.

Comment: Is it because the building and tuning of such circuits is so difficult that one needs a PhD, or is it because there are commercial and/or military interests ?

Comment: If you have only a little experience, then GHz are tricky... Maybe try mini-circuits.

Comment: If you just want to make a 1-transistor amplfier, you probably don't need a Ph.D., but you probably do need some previous experience with rf circuits (construction techniques, etc) to get it to work.

Comment: @The photon. Thank you for your answers in general. I do have some (restricted) experience in building elementary circuits, and a good basis in physics and electricity, but probably not enough background regarding construction techniques. Can you indicate me some comprehensible sources for these techniques ?

Comment: @George Herold. I don't understand your suggestion. Do you suggest me to buy an amplifier from "mini-circuit" shop ?

Comment: @MikeTeX, Yes,  Though I know I'm not suppose to give shopping suggestions.  This??  http://www.minicircuits.com/pdfs/ZX60-183A+.pdf

Comment: Thank you so many (I haven't hit on it while surfing in this site); it seems excellent, and not so expensive, even if it can be used only from 5GHz. I will probably envisage buying it. Nevertheless, amplifier is only a part of my project. I really need to learn how to deal with such transistors (in fact, I also need to learn how to deal with negative resistance diodes, the subject of a future thread I'll try to post here).

Comment: @The photon. I am already astonished from your answer. Is it possible that people make a PhD on this relatively well known subject without any book ? But maybe did you mean that this matter has to be found in papers and specialized articles. In this case, do you know some comprehensible articles that have some chance to help me.

Comment: Usually you have to read many books to get a Ph.D., and also get practical experience from project work and research.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There aren't many complete references for HEMTs or pHEMTs. It may be because they're relatively new and specialized. I think it's because they're just another variation in the FET family.

Most people learn to initially use FETs by studying MOSFETs and then MESFETs. HEMT/pHEMT usage is so similar to MESFETs, most MESFET techniques can be used without changing a thing. This is why most references are focused on a specific difference, and do not cover general HEMT usage.

Here are a few "RF 101" books I would start with...
Pozar, Microwave Engineering

Ludwig, RF Circuit Design

If you still want something specific to HEMTs...

Golio, Microwave MESFETs and HEMTs

Comment: Just to know: what is "RF 101 books" (I haven't been successful with google)

Comment: At US university's, the first class towards a degree is often numbered 101. To get a degree in radio frequency, you might start by taking a class called RF 101. I guess I didn't consider that it's limited to the US.